# View public key(s) exchange during https handshake from the command line

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, public-key

It is possible to view the entire HTTPS session from start to end? Any command line I can run?

I am interested in understanding more about the exchange of the public key(s) in order to establish a secure connection between (for example) a client and a webserver (website).

I will be happy just to see the entire HTTPS (handshake session) between my laptop and any HTTP website.

Comment: Handshake can be viewed with Wireshark (GUI) or its command line equivalent tshark.

Comment: Does it count if it is a list of commands comprising installing wireshark and/or a TLS proxy 

Comment: wireshark, tshark, and tcpdump. What you are looking for is a "packet capture" program or script.

Comment: @schroeder I can not use wireshark/tshark. what about tcpdump does it come by default on Windows/MacOS? if yes what is the command that I need to execute just something like:
tcpdump https://website.com   ?????

Comment: You want a tool that is built-in? Why? And yes, tcpdump comes with MacOS. Look up how to use it online. Tons of tutorials. All of this has nothing to do with security.

Comment: For TLS 1.3 the server cert (and client cert if used) are encrypted, so wireshark (and tshark) can display their actual values only if one of your endpoints exports the session secrets in SSLKEYLOGFILE format -- Firefox and Chrome browsers can if configured; other programs vary. (I haven't tried new Edge=Chrome.) The (FF/EC)DHE key 'shares' however are cleartext in all protocol versions. Or you can see an example with detailed explanation of someone else's session at `{tls13,tls12}.xargs.org` (also QUIC which is not HTTPS but is used for websites, and DTLS which is not).